# Cordova and AdMob Pro Plugin - App slow down after return from device menu

Tags: cordova, admob, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

For several months I have a problem with admob plugins in my applications. If I turn on the application, everything works fine until I return to the device's menu without removing the application from the memory and after returning the application slows down considerably. I can't determine what creates this error.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue that admob slows down cordova applications. If the ads are already loaded in the beginning, you will probably notice a delay when you start your app. Place it on other pages of your app to prevent this.

Comment: I am aware of the slowing down of the application when loading ads, the problem I am struggling with is completely different because the application slows down very much until the reset, I recently noticed that the ads do not pause when exiting, they only destroy or hide. The best part is that with one of the compilations that did not differ from the previous ones (at least that the code pages) after exiting the device menu slowed down but with a few attempts to enter and exit again works correctly.